# What is the purpose of adding a random number to the URL of a login form?

Tags: javascript, web

What exactly is the purpose of sending a math.random nocache parameter when having a login form post to a server handler?

```
var email = encodeURI(document.getElementById('emailLogin').value);
var psw = encodeURI(document.getElementById('pswLogin').value);
// Set te random number to add to URL request
nocache = Math.random();
// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'login.php?email='+email+'&psw='+psw+'&nocache = '+nocache);
```

Comment: To ensure the server response from the login attempt is a new one every time, and not treated like any other cached resource

Comment: browsers, and more specifically chrome can use very aggressive caching schemes where the request doesn't go to the server but access a local old copy, still this seems very wrong you should never transmit credentials via a url unencrypted, anyone monitoring the wire can grab them ...

Comment: A login should be a POST request anyway, which is not cached.

Answer (score 7):

The random number added to request is to force the browser to load the following page result, rather than potentially displaying one which might have been cached by an earlier request.

For what its worth --- this appears to be a quite insecure authenticator -- unless the http.open() is occurring on an HTTPS (SSL/TLS) connection.